# rdd(row) remove duplicates within a partition using mapPartitions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have a DF which is partitioned and sorted already on all the columns. Now I want to remove duplicates only in each partition. ( Duplicates will not span across partitions). I cannot use `df.distinct()`, as it is causing shuffle and I want to avoid shuffle. I converted the df to rdd and used `mapPartitions`. I am getting the output but it is running really slow. How to optimize this? Below is my code.

```
def unique_values(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    previous = next(it)
    yield previous
    for item in it:
        if item != previous:
            previous = item
            yield item
            
rdd = df.rdd.mapPartitions(unique_values)

df = ..converting rdd back to df...
```

Spark version : 2.4.4 on EMR 5.28

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume dataframe `df` which is partitioned and sorted already on all the columns.

### Assign partition id to each row

```scala
val partitionDF = df.withColumn("partitionId", spark_partition_id())
```

### group by based on `partitionId` and `all_columns` to get distinct in each partition

```scala
partitionDF.groupBy(partitionDF.columns.map(col): _*).count()
```

Comment: Adding another column and group by on that adds another shuffle. I am trying to avoid any more shuffles.

Comment: What is the intention here? IIUC, the primary requirement is to drop duplicates within a partition which above solution is doing well. Can I ask you what do you wanted to achieve after that?

Comment: Intention here is to use rdd operatiobs to avoid any more shuffle.